# how to delete null value in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

[image]
This is my first time to ask StackOverflow so if I tell strange something, please let me know smoothly.

I want to predict accuracy in this dataset.
But I don't know how to accept or delete nan or null values using pandas or numpy and how to get right accuracy and loss in this model.

And I tried to use `isnull` function in pandas but it didn't work.

I think the reason why the value of accuracy and loss are not calculated is that the value set as `X` belongs to the null value.

so I want to know how to except nan or null values.

if you have a similar case or solve this problem, please let me know how to solve this problem. thanks!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXrAa.png 
this is shape of dataset.

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1) Please do not use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your post instead 2) please see why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

You said you don't know how to delete nan values in pandas or numpy, but some times we don't delete them, we replace them. For example you could put zero for non values for a feature, or you can calculate average value of that feature and use it.

To remove rows with nan values you could do that

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [2,3,np.nan,5],
              [np.nan,5,2,3]])
x = x[~np.isnan(x).any(axis=1)]
```

output:

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 4.]])
```

Or to replace Nan with some thing else like 0, for numpy array:

```
x[np.isnan(x)] = 0
```

output

```
x:
array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [2., 3., 0., 5.],
       [0., 5., 2., 3.]])
```

In pandas dataframe, you can remove a specific column with Nan elemnt

```
x = np.array([[np.nan,2,3,4],
          [2,3,np.nan,5],
          [3,5,2,3]])
xpd = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["A","B","C","D"])
xpd = xpd[pd.notnull(xpd['A'])]
```

output

```
xpd
     A    B    C    D
1  2.0  3.0  NaN  5.0
2  3.0  5.0  2.0  3.0
```

or remove a row with Nan element

```
xpd:
     A    B    C    D
2  3.0  5.0  2.0  3.0
```

and also you can replace nan value with some thing else in padas dataframe

```
xpd = xpd.replace([np.nan], 0)
```

output

```
xpd:
     A    B    C    D
0  0.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  2.0  3.0  0.0  5.0
2  3.0  5.0  2.0  3.0
```